# Getting last Monday from today at a specific time

Tags: python, datetime

I have logic in my app that requires to do some aggregation based on the last monday at noon. Right now I have gotten it working with getting the last Monday without consideration of time of day. I do that like so:

```
today = datetime.now()
last_monday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
last_monday = last_monday.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

This works if it's since Monday at 12am. I need everything that has happened since the last Monday at 12pm utc (last Monday from today). Does anyone know how to do this? I need this because I would like to do something like

```
last_monday_at_12pm = *answer*

if last_monday_at_12pm < date_to_compare:
    * then do something *
```

Comment: You specifically set `hour=0`, and note this gives you midnight. Did you try setting `hour=12`?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Could you describe it more?

Comment: What is vague? I want to check if any given date is greater than the last Monday at 12pm (relative to `datetime.now`), honestly can't be more clearer than that.

Comment: To make the question more clear, I suggest you use 24h format, not am/pm (so that there is only one 1200h). Then, you also should be more precise regarding time zones; it is unclear right now if all the dates you work with are in UTC or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.8, you might be able to make use of the `isocalendar` feature for this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_lastmonday_1200(dtobj):
    # check if input date is monday:
    week_offset = 1 if dtobj.weekday() == 0 else 0
    # use isocalendar() to get week and day number:
    year, week, _ = dtobj.isocalendar()
    # create the datetime object "last monday",
    # note that monday is day=1 (not 0):
    return datetime.fromisocalendar(year, week-week_offset, 1).replace(hour=12, tzinfo=dtobj.tzinfo)


print(get_lastmonday_1200(datetime(2020, 3, 3))) # expect 2020-3-2 12:00
# 2020-03-02 12:00:00
print(get_lastmonday_1200(datetime(2020, 3, 8))) # expect 2020-3-2 12:00
# 2020-03-02 12:00:00
print(get_lastmonday_1200(datetime(2020, 3, 9))) # expect 2020-3-2 12:00
# 2020-03-02 12:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

The below snippet returns the last Monday of now.

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_monday = now - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday())
```

In the same way as above, you can get the last Monday for each specific date and time. For example consider the following snippet:

```py
import datetime

moment = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=12, day=13)
last_monday = moment - datetime.timedelta(days=moment.weekday())
```

The above snippet returns the last Monday of 2019/12/13 at 00:00. So for your situation, you can do like this:

```py
import datetime

moment = datetime.datetime(
    year=2019, month=12, day=13,
    hour=12, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0
)
last_monday_at_12pm = moment - datetime.timedelta(days=moment.weekday())

if last_monday_at_12pm < date_to_compare:
    # do something
    pass
```

Finally you can get the last Monday from today like below:

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
today_noon = now.replace(hour=12, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
last_monday_at_12pm = today_noon - datetime.timedelta(days=today_noon.weekday())

if last_monday_at_12pm < date_to_compare:
    # do something
    pass
```

Comment: It's the last monday at 12pm from today.

Comment: @10xprogrammer20x My answer was under completion but now is completed

Comment: @10xprogrammer20x No, it's from specific date (2019/12/13)

Comment: You aren't understanding my question. I want the last Monday at 12pm **from today**.

Comment: @10xprogrammer20x Your question doesn't make sense at all. I've updated my answer. Let's check it! Please comment before downvote. I may improve my answer...

Comment: @10xprogrammer20x I've tested all the snippets. All of them works correctly. Also the last one is what you wanted (the last Monday at 12pm from today). I don't know what's wrong with you. give more clues...

Comment: @10xprogrammer20x What happens when you run the last snippet? What do you want to compare with?

Comment: @mrzm `last_monday = now - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday())` won't work if "now" is monday... sidenote: 10xprogrammer20x is not yet allowed to downvote (needs 125 rep).